# What changes are there between Eclipse RCP Juno and Luna

Tags: eclipse-rcp

Does anyone know of any changes that were made in possible ways to migrate from Eclipse Juno to Luna RCP and how that impacts a migration from Indigo? The only articles I've seen that deal with changes from Juno to Luna were for native e4 apps.

I can find articles that discuss how to go from Indigo to Juno, but I also want to be abreast of the improvements from Juno to Luna, so I can make the best decision regarding whether my company should migrate up. For example, it would be good to know if mixing Eclipse 4 and Eclipse 3.x. components are now officially supported in Luna, because they weren't in Juno.

Comment: Sorry but this is far too broad. Eclipse has dozens of components all with changes from Eclipse Juno -> Kepler and Kepler -> Luna. Search for 'whats new in Eclipse xxx' to find the various help documents on this.

Comment: What I'm referring to specifically are the issues relating to the compatibility layer that was developed when applications were migrated from 3.x to 4.x. I found articles that dealt with the issues involving Indigo to Juno, such as : http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/06/18/migrating-from-eclipse-3-x-to-eclipse-4-e4/ but I'm looking for a compatibility layer article that deals with Juno to Luna so I can know the specific subset of issues relating to compatibility layer changes from Indigo to Luna.